# Need Simple way to load some Config Settings for App

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, config, ini

Visual Studio 2010 C# .Net 4.0 Windows Forms App

I have several configuration setting that I would like to store in an XML file.

I want to load values from the XML file for: Background Color, Input Port, TimeOut Seconds, and Region
This is a very specific project and it will have just to 4 parameters in total. I do not need this to be flexible. I need it simple. Have been trying for a week now.. all examples I found are not working for my simple file.

My Xml File is basic:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appsettings>
    <bgcolor>BLUE</bgcolor>
    <inputport>1</inputport>
    <timeout>50</timeout>
    <region>USA</region>
</appsettings>
```

Next, I would like to load the XML file at startup and store each value in my string vars.
This is where i am stuck.  I know there must be a very simple way such as:\

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\rm\rmdemo_18\Rmocd001.xml");
    String FormColor = (String)XDoc.Root.Element("appsettings").Element("bgcolor");
    String Region = (String)XDoc.Root.Element("appsettings").Element("region");
    textLocalization.text = Region;
    textFormColor.text = FormColor;
          etc.....
}
```

Any help or direct would be appreciated please. Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you run your application? Is an exception thrown within `form1_Load`, and if so on which line?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not use the App.config file?

Comment: yes tim there is. For one, I was to be able to use a setup screen to configure the system instead of having someone manually edit the file. Also, I am going to be running multiple copies of the executable on different pc's on the network (its running on a POS system at a store).  each one may have a slightly different config.  I will load the station number as a command line arg which will tell it which config file to use.   In the past (VB) this was easy to do with an INI file.. im just not getting this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ConfigurationManager class if you add it to you app.config file.

```
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bgcolor"]
```

If you really need to use Linq to XML you can use.

```
var bgColor =  XDoc.Root.Descendants("bgcolor").First().Value
```

Comment: i get an error in the code:  >>> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'First'

Comment: my bad i think., i had not referenced Linq  testing now